# How to run/execute an adobe AIR file on Linux (ec2/ubuntu) from command line only (no gui)

Tags: linux, bash, air

Im trying to execute a .AIR file on a linux box (ubuntu) from the command line, and disregard the GUI.

Here's the thing. About 6mo I was able to do this, but I forgot how I did it, and I'm left to figure out how it was done by looking at clues on the server.

- I see the MainSimple.air file that I had originally used.
- I see that I somehow installed it into /opt/MainSimple/bin/MainSimple (which is now a binary file, not an air)
- I see my script file to run that file, and it successfully executes.

--- runAir.sh ---

```
  #!/bin/sh
  export DISPLAY=:2
  /opt/MainSimple/bin/MainSimple &
```

So my question is, now that I have a new/different air file... how do I get it to "install" or change/compile into a binary file like I did before?

I know an .air file is just a zip file.. I unzipped it, and theirs no /bin directory in it.

Answer (score 4):

To install an air application from command-line, you can try this:

```
ln -s "/opt/Adobe AIR/Versions/1.0/Adobe AIR Application Installer" /usr/sbin/airinstall
```

The above command will create a symbolic link for Air Application Installer. Then, to install an air app:

```
airinstall app.air
```

To execute/run the air application, locate the binary file of your air application then run it on terminal:

```
/opt/MainSimple/bin/MainSimple &
```

Comment: thank you for the info. Unfortunately that installer needs a gui to install the "-silent" command doesnt work with linux. What I ended up doing was installing a gui and connecting via VNC... I couldnt figure out how to install it without a gui.